# Is there a way to do a "Contains" Query in Salesforce/SOQL that picks up that word in a sentence, but not if it's part of a word?

Tags: salesforce, crm, soql, salesforce-lightning

Example: I want to find NATO accounts that say NATO ___ so I can't use equals, but things like "Donato's" are appearing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the space in your LIKE clause, i.e.

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'NATO %'
```